# M2: reason add-to-cart might not function in production mode

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1, addtocart

I set up a new site recently while in `default` mode and set it to `production` mode. Everything worked except for the add-to-cart function for guest customers. Once logged in as a customer, add-to-cart would work normally. Caching was also on the whole time in production mode.

I change mode to `developer`, and all worked fine. I changed it back to `production`, and now it works fine for any visitors.

There was no change in file or in DB. Any idea what could have happened? I'm unable to replicate this issue. The issue was replicable on three different computers while it was happening.

Comment: You enable Guest check out admin? Did you remove local Storage? Because the config is stored on local Storage browser.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, didn't remove any browser cache. It was happening for multiple people on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Magento 2 behavior in different modes. While you are running Magento 2 in developer mode, everything in var/generation or pub/static will be generated automatically. If you switch between the three modes, the configuration files change! The production mode doesn't generate anything by default. So if your mode is developer, you don't have to care about anything. If you run Magento 2 in production mode, you have to create all the assets by yourself.

Run...

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --jobs=1
```

...to create everything for production!

Also check the following site to get an overview of the three different modes in Magento 2:

[All About Magento 2 Modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)